# Trocar logo de acordo com a página

Tags: php, javascript, html, imagem, sintaxe

Olá.
Preciso que o logo do site troque de acordo com a página que o usuário visita.
Tenho um site feito em PHP no qual o topo é um `include`. Por isso pensei em trocar o logo via Javascript.

Coloquei o `ID="logo"` na `img` e um `ID` no `body` das páginas que terão um logo diferente. Assim esperava que através do `If`/`Else`, verificando se havia ou não o `ID` no `body`, o `src` da imagem se alterasse. Mas não está rolando. Não sou programador e cheguei até aqui pesquisando no Google. rs

Eis meus códigos:

HTML

`<img id="logo" src="<?=$img_dir?>/logo_ultraclimber-resgate.png" alt="Ultra Climber Treinamentos e Serviços" />`

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ('body[id="treina"]') {
    document.getElementById("logo").src='_include/images/logo_ultraclimber-treinamentos.png';
} if else ('body[id="serv"]') {
    document.getElementById("logo").src='_include/images/logo_ultraclimber-servicos.png';
} else {
    document.getElementById("logo").src='_include/images/logo_ultraclimber-resgate.png';
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!
=]

Comment: Como está feito o seu menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazer em JS isso num site em PHP é meio que uma "gambiarra". O ideal é resolver isso no PHP mesmo.

Por exemplo, criando uma variável antes do include:

<sub>paginaresgate.php</sub>

```
<?php
   $logo = 'logo_ultraclimber-resgate.png';
   include( '__topo.php' );

   ... resto da pagina
```

E no `__topo.php` você simplesmente troca a linha com o logo *hardcoded* por algo desse tipo, que seta uma variável, ou usa a provida pelo usuário:

<sub>__topo.php</sub>

```
<?php
   ... 
   if ( !isset( $logo ) ) $logo = 'logo_default.png'; // caso não seja setado na página
   echo '<img id="logo" src="'.$img_dir.'/'.$logo.' alt="ultraclimber...">';
   ...
```

Notar que tem muitas outras maneiras de resolver o problema, mas esta proposta aqui serve não apenas para o logo, como também para o `<title>` da página, o `<alt>` da imagem ou qualquer outro dado variável que não mude significativamente a estrutura do topo.

Comment: Show de bola cara!! Funfou direitinho! Salvou! Brigadão! =D